# Ignoring Strings, Text, and Whitespace using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

Was looking around for ways to ignore text at the end of an input file in my program.  Found a neat was to ignore strings, text, characters, and white space while using `fscanf()` :

```
    fscanf(input_file, "%*[a-zA-Z \t]*", temp);
```

If you have an input file e.g. `*.txt` that has unwanted text at the end of the input line, using `fscanf()` and regex expressions will eat that up and ignore it.  `temp` is a `char*` for the sake of having a string buffer available in `fsanf()`.

Comment: `fscanf()` won't recognize regular expression. The `*` at the end of format string means that `*` is expected there and the argument `temp` will be evaluated and ignored because what is read won't be stored because `*` option is there.

Comment: What is your question? If your purpose is to just share what you know, please separate it to question and answer.

Comment: What's the question?  How to do it properly?

Comment: If you just want to skip the remainder of an input line, use `"%*[^\n]"`.

Comment: How to I make it an answer? Apologies for posting it as a question

Comment: I just wonder what the last `*` is for. The rest can be found in the man-page or any other documentation of the `scanf` functions. But you are wrong assuming it "eats up" whitespace. It just skips spaces and tabs. And passing a buffer is not necessary, as that's what the first `*` is for.

Comment: `How to I make it an answer` You can answer your own question. Before you do that, however, make sure that the title, question, and answer all match. As you have it now, the question refers to `text and whitespace` but `"%*[a-zA-Z \t]"` only skips over _letters_ and spaces/tabs - for example it will not _ignore_ text such as `1*?`.